# Excel IF (Then) formula

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking for a formula that looks at column F3 through F10 for 'open' then looks at column E3 through F10 for 'yes' then returns a value from column D3 through D10....is there such a way to do this?  TIA!
I used to be a wiz at formulas a few jobs ago but lately I haven't had a need for them so I've lost my touch.

Comment: I think you need =IF(AND(IF(...),IF(..), [True], [False]) Use VLOOKUP in the AND(IF(

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria or https://www.contextures.com/excellookupmultiplecriteriaindexmatch.html

Comment: VLOOKUP! that might do the trick, thanks!

Comment: Actually vlookup might not work...I'm not looking to match, I'm looking for a formula to look at several columns and give me an answer based on certain words.  Maybe the formula I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: That last statement is doubtful. If you [edit our question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55054869/edit) and provide sample data and expected outcome, we'll be able to come up with more specific suggestions.

Comment: Wow...thanks cybernatic.nomad, didn't need that when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

In Row3 of a spare column and copied down to Row10

```
=IF(AND(E4="yes",F4="open"),D4,"")
```

should repeat in the corresponding rows only the ColumnD values in the same row as a `yes` in ColumnE and an `open` in ColumnF.